# Error deleting latest version of a file using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: typescript, microsoft-graph-api, nestjs, sharepoint-2013

I'm working on a task where I need to delete a document from a SharePoint library using the Microsoft Graph API. I have implemented a deleteDocument function that accepts the fileName, folderName, fileExtension, and versionId as parameters.

The function retrieves the libraryId based on the folderName provided, and then attempts to get the item information using the API call client.api('/sites/${this.siteId}/lists/${libraryId}/drive/root:/${fileName}${fileExtension}').get().

If the versionId parameter is provided, the code attempts to delete a specific version of the document using the API call client.api('/sites/${this.siteId}/lists/${libraryId}/drive/items/${item.id}/versions/${versionId}').delete(). Otherwise, it deletes the entire document using client.api('/sites/${this.siteId}/lists/${libraryId}/drive/items/${item.id}').delete().

The problem I'm facing is that when I provide the latest versionId of the file, it throws an error stating that the latest version cannot be deleted. I would like to know how to handle this situation properly and delete the latest version of the document.

```
public async deleteDocument(
  fileName: string,
  folderName: string,
  fileExtension?: string,
  versionId?: string
): Promise<void> {
  const libraryId = await this.getLibraryIdByLibraryName(folderName);
  if (!libraryId) {
    throw new DocumentStorageException(`Library "${folderName}" not found`);
  }
  const client = await this.getClient();

  const item = await client
    .api(
      `/sites/${this.siteId}/lists/${libraryId}/drive/root:/${fileName}${fileExtension}`
    )
    .get();

  if (!item.id) {
    throw new DocumentStorageException(
      `File "${fileName}" not found in library "${folderName}"`
    );
  }

  if (versionId) {
    await client
      .api(
        `/sites/${this.siteId}/lists/${libraryId}/drive/items/${item.id}/versions/${versionId}`
      )
      .delete();
  } else {
    // Delete the entire document
    await client
      .api(`/sites/${this.siteId}/lists/${libraryId}/drive/items/${item.id}`)
      .delete();
  }
}
```

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to properly handle the deletion of the latest version of a file or restore just previous version of the same file, using the Microsoft Graph API. Thank you in advance for your help!

I have already attempted to delete the file but encountered this issue only for the latest version.

Comment: I would [restore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitemversion-restore?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) the previous version. It becomes the current version. Then I would delete the version which was the latest before restoring previous version.